# Why doesn't the transfer-principle hold for the following statement?

Tags: nonstandard-models

Let $\hat{V}$ be the standard universe constructed as 
 
$ \hat{V} = V_0\cup V_1 \cup V_2 \cup ....$ 
where 
$V_0$ is the set of primary elements and
$V_{v+1} := V_v \cup P(V_v)$

For the following (failed) proof we assume $V_0 = \mathbb{N}$. 
Given then whole non-standard course we also got a transfer-function and a transfer-principle.

Now, I was trying to transfer the statement "Every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has a smallest element", as formula:

$(\forall A\in V_2)\bigg(A\subset\mathbb{N} \Leftrightarrow (\exists a\in A)\big((\forall b\in A)(a\le b)\big)\bigg)$

The magic $V_2$ is used there, as $V_2 = P(P(V_0))$ contains all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ as elements.

Given the transfer principle, this should transfer to a formula where all standard-elements are exchanged with non-standard-elements, in this case
$V_2 \,\text{ by } \,^*V_2\quad$and $\quad\mathbb{N}\,$ by $\,^*\mathbb{N}\quad$ and$\quad$  $\le$ $\,$ by $\,$ *≤

Finally, the transferred formula should look like this:

$(\forall A\in {^*V_2})\bigg(A\subset\mathbb{^*N} \Leftrightarrow (\exists a\in A)\big((\forall b\in A)(a $ *≤ $ b)\big)\bigg)$

It looks right, but as $\mathbb{^*N}$ contains infinitely infinite elements, I can construct a subset $\mathbb{^*N}-\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{^*N}$ that "defies" the proof.

E.g. say $x\in\mathbb{^*N-N}$ is the smallest element of the set. Then $x-1$ is smaller, yet infinite, and as such member of $\mathbb{^*N-N}$.

So, somewhere along the line I must have made a mistake or (more probable) misunderstood something. But what is it?

Comment: To begin with, not every subset of $\Bbb N$ has a smallest element ...

Comment: ... but I suppose the main point is that ${}^*V_1$ is not $P({}^*V_0)$, i.e., not *all* subsets of ${}^*\Bbb N$, but only those that are extensions of subsets of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Ahh, the empty set

Comment: But shouldn't it be? $V_{v+1} = P(V_v)\cup V_v$ is a true statement for $\hat{V}$, so the transfer of it should be true as well, shouldn't it? <br> (Though I can find no way to express P(...) in a sensible way)

Comment: That's exactly the point. $P(...)$ is not very first-order

Comment: Okay... so does that mean that actually, $\hat{^*V}$ isn't build up analogue to $\hat{V}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64114/discussion-between-sudix-and-hagen-von-eitzen).